# strlen result changes with and without a prior printf

Tags: c, http

I'm starting to build a C function that breaks an HTTP request string apart on "\r\n".

The function creates short local buffers for each row of the HTTP request, where each row is the
sub string between `char *front` and the location of the next delimiter.

However, I'm seeing that the call to `strlen()` on line 150 reports two different lengths for the request-header depending on whether or not the `printf()` calls on lines 146 and 147 are present.

When they are included, `150  strlen(header)` returns `21` (where header = "Host: www.example.com")
Without the `printf()` statements, `150  strlen(header)` returns `30`, so the `printf()` on line `152` includes garbage at the end (`Host: www.example.com HT*ԩU`)

```c
struct http_request *string_to_request(char *req, size_t req_len) {
  char *front = req;
  const char *delim = "\r\n";
  size_t delim_len = strlen(delim);

  char *c = strstr(front, delim);

  if (c > front) {
    size_t request_line_len = c - front;
    char request_line[request_line_len];
    strncpy(request_line, front, request_line_len);

    printf("%s\n", request_line);
    front += strlen(request_line) + delim_len;

    c += delim_len;
  }

  c = strstr(front, delim);
  size_t header_line_len = c - front;
  char header[header_line_len];
  strncpy(header, front, header_line_len);

  printf("%s\n", header);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char header[(long)c - (long)front];` do you really have to declare like that instead of `char header[REASONABLE_ENOUGH_SIZE] = {0};`, this will avoid such problems

Comment: That's a good point - had I zeroed out the buffer on init, it would have avoided the issue altogether. My big question was how and why the printf() statements changed the results of strlen, which @joshua answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `strncpy` to construct a non null-terminated string. Trying to pass it to `printf` would only work if you used a string length argument, and `strlen` won't work at all. The string is exactly `c - front` characters long, so as far as that goes, you can replace the `strlen` call with `c - front`.

So I'm pretty sure you're intending to do something else where that `printf` call is. You have two design choices to make.

1. You can abandon null-terminated strings and use counted strings for whatever you intend to call here.
2. You can allocate one more byte on that array and initialize it to zero and pass it to normal string functions.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the non null-terminated string. Any idea why having printf()'s makes such a difference?

Comment: @donny-nyc: Undefined behavior. Probably disturbed something on the stack.